# Wht is the best opensource NLP tool to use with Solr

Tags: solr, nlp

We are looking for an opensource NLP framework to integrate with Solr.We want our users to be able to query our search engine in natural language.

We are considering Standford NLP,NLKT,OpenNLP ,UIMA .

Please suggest.

Regards,
Sireesha

Comment: Solr integrates OpenNLP and (old version of) UIMA, but both of those are used to process the text being indexed. Querying in the natural language is a different problem and possibly a much harder one. I am not sure any of the libraries you list do 'natural language'->'search terms' mapping. You may want to update the question to give some examples of exactly what you want to achieve.

Comment: Hi Alexandre ,Thank you for your comment.We are currently indexing the non hdfs data and hdfs data (Cloudera) using solr (Tools and parts data ,configuration files).We want our non technical users to be able to search the data in simple English instead of a query/syntax.